# How to change permission of a directory recursively using NSFileManager setAttributes

Tags: objective-c

I'm currently using NSFileManager setAttributes to change the permission of a directory. My problem is that it doesn't appear to do so recursively. Is there any way to force it to do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a built-in method to do this, but it shouldn't be hard to do something like:

```
NSString *path = @"/The/root/directory";
NSDictionary *attributes;   // Assume that this is already setup


NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *subPaths = [fileManager subpathsAtPath:path];
for (NSString *aPath in subPaths) {
    BOOL isDirectory;
    [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:aPath isDirectory:&isDirectory];
    if (isDirectory) {
        // Change the permissions on the directory here
        NSError *error = nil;
        [fileManager setAttributes:attributes ofItemAtPath:aPath error:&error];
        if (error) {
            // Handle the error
        }
    }
}
```

This is untested, but should give you a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *path = @"/User/user/aPath";
NSFileManager *manager = [[[NSFileManager alloc] init] autorelease];
if ([manager fileExistsAtPath: path]) {
  NSDictionary *attrib = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], NSFileGroupOwnerAccountID,
                             [NSNumber numberWithInt:0], NSFileOwnerAccountID,
                             @"root", NSFileGroupOwnerAccountName,
                             @"root", NSFileOwnerAccountName, nil ];
  NSError *error = nil;
  [manager setAttributes:attrib ofItemAtPath:path error:&error];
  NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum = [manager enumeratorAtPath: path];
  NSString *file;
  while (file = [dirEnum nextObject]) {
    [manager setAttributes:attrib ofItemAtPath:[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:file] error:&error];
  }
}
```